# Numpy: Environment variables affecting import

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

If I reset my environment (as shown below), I am unable to import numpy from python but I can import any other module including wxPython.

```
import os
# reset environment
os.environ = {}
# Numpy here will fail!
import numpy
```

import will fail with the following message

> ImportError: Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed. 
>   Most likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy. If
>   you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes
>   all files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.
>
> Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be
>   found.

Does anyone know how to fix this or why it occurs?

p.s. This does not work on windows, but works on linux.

Progress:

Python on windows does not load as its not able to find the libopenblas.dll file. If I do the following, it seems to work

```
import ctypes
ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(r"C:\python27\lib\site- packages\numpy\.libs\libopenblas.BNVRK7633HSX7YVO2TADGR4A5KEKXJAW.gfortran- win_amd64.dll")
import numpy
```

However is there a way to set an environment variable so that this is not necessary?

1. Setting os.environ to {} probably does not reset or change the environment, however I am not sure about this.
2. Windows requires the 'SYSTEMROOT': 'C:\Windows' to be set for some reason...

once these two requirements are met then the import works

Comment: And just to make sure: You _can_ import numpy if you don't do `os.environ = {}`?

Comment: yes that's right I can import numpy without the change to os.environ @Bono does the same occur to you aswell?